# Функция, которая брала сообщение из чата и писала в logs.txt

Tags: python, python-3.x, база-данных

Я бы хотел сделать функцию для моего бота, которая могла брать из разных чатов сообщение пользователя и писать в logs.txt. Вместо **gm** в

```
'w = logs.write('\n' + gm)'
```

должна быть функция, которая записывает в 'logs.txt' в столбик с помощью ('\n') сообщения.

Есть проблема, сам **gm** выводит ошибку, что нужно конвертировать в str. Сам код не работает!

Это пример как мне бы хотелось.

```
import disnake  # библиотека похожая на discord.py
from disnake.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='/', intents=disnake.Intents.all())
client = disnake.Client()

gm = bot.get_message()

with open('logs.txt', 'a') as logs:
    w = logs.write('\n' + gm)


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("George готов к работе ╰(*°▽°*)╯.")

bot.run('TOKEN')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я верно понял вопрос, то решение будет таким

```
import disnake
from disnake.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='/', intents=disnake.Intents.all())
client = disnake.Client()

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    global gm
    gm = message.content
    await write_to_file(gm)
    await bot.process_commands(message)

async def write_to_file(msg):
    with open('logs.txt', 'a') as logs:
        logs.write(msg + '\n')

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("George готов к работе ╰(*°▽°*)╯.")

bot.run('TOKEN')
```

Новое сообщение будет сохраняться в переменной gm, оно передается в функцтю write_to_file и уже пишет в logs
Если с кода выше будет лететь ошибка вот еще вариант

```
import disnake
from disnake.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='/', intents=disnake.Intents.all())

async def write_to_file(msg: str):
    with open('logs.txt', 'a') as logs:
        logs.write(f"{msg}\n")

@bot.event
async def on_message(message: disnake.Message):
    if message.author.bot:
        return  # игнорировать сообщения от ботов
    await write_to_file(message.content)
    await bot.process_commands(message)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("George готов к работе ╰(*°▽°*)╯.")

bot.run('TOKEN')
```

Comment: Большое тебе спасибо. Всё работает)))

Comment: да не за что) отметь ответ, может другим поможет когда-нибудь

Comment: Привет, мне захотелось добавить в эту функцию нововведение. Это писать от кого было написано это сообщение. И ещё, что бы эти сообщения брались из ОПРЕДЕЛЁННОГО канала. Можешь это сделать? Если сделаешь, я буду тебе очень благодарен)